# NetworkError: 400 Bad Request in WCF Restfull services

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have create a WCF Restfull services , But When I'm calling `POST` method It It's giving me error `**NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:55827/ProductService.svc/CreateStudent**"`

This is my interface

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IProductService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/ProductName/{productID}",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetProductName(string productID);


        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "CreateStudent",  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        bool CreateStudent(Student student);    
    }
```

and My service class

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class ProductService : IProductService
    {
        public string GetProductName(string productID)
        {
            return "ProductName";
        }      
        public bool CreateStudent(Student student)
        {
            var x = 1;
            if (student != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Student    
    {   
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

and web.config for WCF is

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default"
               name="RESTFulWCFService.ProductService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RESTFulWCFService.IProductService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

I have checked all the links but didn't get any solution

**[WCF 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492522/wcf-400-bad-request)**

[**WCF service 400 bad request**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161680/wcf-service-400-bad-request)

**[WCF Service returns 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357852/wcf-service-returns-400-bad-request)**

My JS code

```
 var st = {};
        st.Name = "A";
        st.Address = "B";
        st.Age = 8;
        $.ajax({        
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:55827/ProductService.svc/CreateStudent",
            data: JSON.stringify(st),            
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                debugger;
                alert('no');
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have a similar problem with feathers request framework. The reason is that the JS is using single quotes around property name where as WCF only accepts double quotes.